# Xamarin Android TextToSpeech.Speak doesn't say anything if run from any of the lifecycle methods

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm using an instance of TextToSpeech to convert some text, using the Speak() method, like so:

```
textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(context, this, "com.google.android.tts");
textToSpeech.SetPitch(1f);
textToSpeech.SetSpeechRate(1f);
textToSpeech.Speak(textToConvert, QueueMode.Flush, null, null);
```

The function runs fine with no errors, but the speech can only actually be heard (and the isSpeaking property only changes to true) when the function is not called from the lifecycle methods.

I've tried placing it in OnCreate(), OnStart(), and OnResume() all with the same results, although the function runs fine if called from a button event.

Is this a limitation of the class, or something I can fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're calling the Speak() method before the TTS engine has loaded.  It takes a few moments for it to initialize.

Fortunately, the TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener interface provides a way to know when the engine has successfully loaded via the OnInit() method.

So, if you want your app to speak in OnCreate(), you'll need to move the Speak() method to the OnInit() method.  Here's a working example I put together for you...

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Speech.Tts;

namespace XamdroidMaster.Activities {

    [Activity(ParentActivity = typeof(MainActivity), Label = "Text to Speech")]
    public class TextToSpeechActivity : Activity, TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener {

        private TextToSpeech tts;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.TextToSpeech);

            // Create text to speech object (first parameter: context; second parameter: object implementing TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener)
            // Note that it may take a few moments for the TTS engine to initialize (OnInit() will fire when it's ready)
            tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this, "com.google.android.tts");            
        }

        public void OnInit([GeneratedEnum] OperationResult status) {
            if (status == OperationResult.Success) {
                tts.SetPitch(1f);
                tts.SetSpeechRate(1f);
                tts.Speak("Hello Luke!", QueueMode.Flush, null);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Also, by initializing the TTS engine in OnCreate() as I've shown in the example, you should then be able to fire the Speak() command later in OnResume().

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that TTS engine initialization takes some time. If initialization is not over, the speak method call will fail.
If you "say" something on button click, you will probably won't need this, because user will take some time to think before pressing the button, and the initialization will be over.
If you want to "say" something as soon initialization finishes, use this code：

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private static  TextView speechtext;
    private static  TextToSpeech saytext;       

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);

        speechtext = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

        saytext = new TextToSpeech(this, new MyListener(), "com.google.android.tts");


    }

    class MyListener : Java.Lang.Object, TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener
    {

        public void OnInit([GeneratedEnum] OperationResult status)
        {
            if(status==OperationResult.Success)
            {
                saytext.SetLanguage(Locale.Us);
                saytext.SetPitch(1.5f);
                saytext.SetSpeechRate(1.5f);
                saytext.Speak(speechtext.Text, QueueMode.Flush, null, null);
            }

        }
    }
}
```